# Cannot index into a null array.error with Sharepoint 2010

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use the script below to get some data out from a list.
I'm using it for my Sp 2007 and it workd but when using it under SP 2010 i get the error.
Any ideas.
THanks

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At \64284ccd-adc9-4ae4-be4c-0fcd744be7c1.ps1:12 char:19
+     Title = $item[ <<<< "Title"]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Title:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray



[System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site    =     new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://mysite/Intranet")                                                       

$web     = $site.rootweb                                                                                               
$list    =    $web.Lists["Comms"]

$Responses = @()


foreach ($item in $list.items) {
#$list.Items | foreach {
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Title = $item["Title"]

}
$obj |select-object Title
$Responses += $obj
}
Write-Host $Response
```

Answer (score 1):

Debugging PowerShell generally involves inspecting the values of intermediate variables. In this case, it is obvious from the error that $item is null.  This probably means that $list.items is $null.  This means either the items property is null or more likely that $list is null.  You can check if $list is null like so: `$list -eq $null`.  If it is null, makes sure the $web variable isn't null.  If it isn't then enumerate the web lists like so `$web.Lists` to see if "Comms" shows up.